# Load local host URL in 2nd tab runs 1st tab to same URL faster. Why?

Tags: php, apache, tabs

When a single tab is open to the url:

http://localhost/soccer/public/index.php

and a second tab is open to

http://localhost/soccer/public/games.php

If the first tab is taking a long time, *(3 seconds or more)*, to execute/load then going to the 2nd tab and reloading/refreshing causes the 1st tab to load "instantly".

I can't understand why loading a different tab would force the 1st tab to load any faster. The browser is latest Chrome.  It is a WAMP set up running PHP 7.

The URL can change to any one of the local sites I have and the results are always the same; refreshing the 2nd tab loads the 1st tab immediately.

Thanks for shedding any light on this curiosity.

Code tax:

```
$query = "SHOW TABLES";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$r = $stmt->execute();
echo "completed";
```

Comment: Without seeing *any* code we have no idea how to answer your question.

Comment: It is independent of the code.  I can put "sample" code up there, but since it is code independent, it really doesn't matter.  However, since we all like code I'll edit the question to show some code

Comment: `index.php` and `games.php` contain the same code?